# Learning to sing: Some songs i can sing straightforwardly other i really cant is this normal?

Tags: voice, melody, voice-leading, pitch, voice-training

I've been learning to sing for a year. And I noticed some great improvements but there is one thing that happens to me that is totally strange: When I listen to songs, there are songs that I can "understand" right away and then I can sing them with the right notes after practically a few plays.
There are other songs that maybe I have known for a long time, that no matter how much I listen to them I can't sing them and I can't "understand" them at all. ( i sing totally wrong)
Is this normal for a beginner?

For instance:
Passing Afternoon by iron and wine is one of the song i struggle the most.(I'm A 24yo male)

Comment: It's a good idea to learn to play an instrument at the same time - you'll have a far better understanding of how music works then.

Comment: @Tim yes i'm learning guitar too !

Comment: What's the nature of the songs that you "sing totally wrong"? Do they have really fast notes? Are they atonal or at least heavily chromatic? Do they switch keys too often? Do they have prominent countermelodies you wish you could sing at the same time as the main melody?

Comment: @Dekkadeci well i cant tell you why those are so hard for me but i can give you exemples of song i find impossible to sing: Passing afternoon by iron and wine , ghost by justin bieber i really can't sing them .   instead songs like "little things, tusk till down , yellow (coldplay) i can at least sing decently/good   ( ps if this matter i'm a 24yo male)

Comment: Could be range, but that's mentioned by other comments already. Could also be intervals - some intervals are less familiar and harder to get the hang of. Also, a song with an uncommonly fast or slow tempo might feel unusual and take longer to get the hang of.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unusual, maybe!   My experience is that when a singer learns by imitation, there's little distinction between 'hard' and 'easy' (as long as the song is in their vocal range).   It's when reading notation that a complex song becomes 'hard'.

Maybe you're trying songs that AREN'T in your vocal range.   If you're a female soprano, you might have to re-think a James Brown song!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well i give you some instance: i can get "little things the one written by ed sheeran for 1d " very fast, and i sing it quite well. I'm really struggling to sing "passing afternoon by iron and wine , i really can't get it no mutter how much i try!

Comment: Passing afternoon doesn't seems to be this "super high difficult" song , but for me is nearly impossible to sing.